# How to access windows based remote desktop from Linux ubuntu with a known gateway hostname and PC name?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I often use my university's high end Windows PC remotely on my windows 10 laptop. They have provided a bunch of rdp files (https://remoteaccess.labstats.com/Swansea-University) that allows me to connect me to a PC of my choice.

However, whenever I try to connect any of these PCs on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I can't simply connect. I have tried this on Remmina and several others.

Remmina allows to use rdp files directly but still doesn't connects.

Here are the contents of the rdp file.

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1200
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:remotelab.swan.ac.uk
gatewayusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:1
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:

full address:s:WS-P1210334258
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP is a proprietary protocol for the Windows Remote Desktop.
Remmina on Linux does not support a full implementation of the `.rdp` file and may have
problems with more complex `.rdp` files.

You might get better results by starting the Remmina user interface,
opening the `.rdp` file with a text editor, and doing a
copy-paste to Remmina of the server name (WS-P1210334258) and
gateway name (remotelab.swan.ac.uk) and specify the RDP protocol.

Name the connection and "Save" these details, so the next time you open
Remmina the connection will be available for reuse.

Comment: I have tried this so many times. It says, unable to establish connection. Check security protocol negotiation. Also, it asks for the domain. I guess the domain should be remotelab.swan.ac.uk

Comment: Check the advice in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445613/cant-connect-to-remote-server-using-rdp-remmina-after-upgrade). If nothing helps, it's possible that some security measure on the server is rejecting your connection (I tried from Windows with your file and it rejected mine), so ask for help from the uni admin for Computer Labs. You might also try [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) with its real Windows RDP client.

Comment: It should reject your connection. I have the authority as an student, to open the remote connection gateway for a specific PC. So, you can't even connect it. Also, wine doesn't support windows official rdp tool. It required .net framework.

Comment: This leaves three options I can think of: (1) Try [another RDP client](https://linuxkamarada.com/en/2020/04/20/remote-desktop-connection-to-windows-from-linux-using-rdp-clients/) than Remmina. (2) Ask Computer Labs how to connect from Linux. (3) Create a Windows virtual machine to do the RDP. You may get an ISO from the [Download Windows 10 page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). It will be installed as trial and you may need to recreate it once it refuses to work. The Uni might be able to help.

Comment: Actually, my Linux PC is very old. So, I was planning to use the remote computer on that PC and leave my simulations running for 3-4 days. You know fluid simulation takes days. My uni says they can't provide support for Linux lol. What I did is I installed teamviewer on the remote PC and now I can turn on the remote PC from my windows laptop and can connect the teamviewer to one in my Linux PC. The only problem is I can't close the rdp connection on my windows laptop else the remote PC would shutdown or log out.

Comment: Teamviewer is only a viewer so closing it shouldn't cause any program on the server to close, if no one else is using the remote computer.

Comment: No. When I close the rdp from my laptop the computer logs out. And I can no longer use teamviewer from my linux PC to the remote PC.

Comment: I have used Teamviewer (a lot) and it's not an RDP, but you need an existing login session on the target computer. If this doesn't exist, and if none of the other RDP clients work for you (I wonder why), then the Windows VM is the only solution left, apart from installing Windows on your computer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I have 3 PCs. A- Windows laptop, B- Linux PC, C- Remote windows PC. I first opened 'C' on 'A' using windows RDP. I installed teamviewer on 'C' using the remote access from 'A'. Then I install teamviewer on 'B', to access 'C'. Everything is fine and works very well. But as I close the RDP on 'A' the 'C' logs me out and I can no longer leverage the teamviewer. Hope its clear now.

Comment: I get confused by your usage of the two terms RDP and Teamviewer.